# How to access REST API from a remote machine?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, http, tomcat

I am writting spring service(rest) for mobile app.I am writing test service with localhost and running on virtual machine(windows) but i can see `http://localhost:8080/rest`only on the same computer.What should i do to use my rest api from another machine?ip

```
aplication properties

spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=
spring.data.mongodb.database=mongoTest
```

Comment: You can use the ipaddress of the machine from which you are exposing the APIs to access it from a remote machine instead of localhost. Localhost can be used while accessing it within the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about two different things.

Your property file is about connection to your mongodb instance.

localhost is only a shortcut "saying" that the application can be found on your local machine.

having localhost in this property file means that the application server and the database server are on the same physical machine.

If you want to access your API from another machine, you can use the IP address of the server.

On Windows, you can know this address by typing ipconfig in a command line.

On Linux, it would be ifconfig.

Later, you can try to work with machine name instead of the IP address.